# Can facebook connect have a profile canvas too?

Tags: php, facebook

I am working with facebook connect.  In facebook app settings, for my connect site app there is an option to allow users to add the app as a tab on there user profile.  When you click the tab on a user profile for my app, it loads nothing on the canvas because I have nothing set.

So I am wanting to know, since I am just using it for connect, can I still show something on the profile tab for my app, I would like to show a message about how my site uses the app on that page if it's even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes, you can !!](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.streamPublish)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a connect site is also an application on Facebook and can do everything an application can. Connecting on your site is the same as authorizing the app on Facebook.