# Can a desktop Facebook app have a canvas page as well?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, desktop-application

Can a desktop Facebook app have a canvas page as well?
We have a desktop app and would like to extend it to include a canvas page.

According to StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972961/can-facebook-connect-have-a-profile-canvas-too) a Facebook Connect can have a canvas page, but I am not sure whether a desktop app can have.